# Time Limit Exceeded Error in algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to convert a number in the divisible of 3
A number can be converted into other number with same number of digits and no leading zeros.

The cost of converting a number into other is the sum of absolute difference of corresponding digits. For example, Cost to convert 235 to 331 is 5 (since the absolute difference in corresponding digits is |3−2|+|3−3|+|1−5| , which is |1|+0+|−4|=5.

```
Number= 66  cost= 3
```

The numbers that can be created within the cost ≤3 of 66 are 36,45,54,57,63,66,69,75,78,87,96. so answer is 11.

**My approach:**
I am taking input as a String and
Using Recursive call make all the combination

```
public static void cal(int len , int sum , int c , String SS){

    if(c>cost) return ;
    if(len==SS.length()){
        if(sum%3==0) ans++;
        return;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
        int xx =Math.abs(i-Character.getNumericValue(SS.charAt(len)));
        cal(current+1, len+1, sum+i, c+xx, SS);
    }
}
```

Since zero is not allowed at MSB so.

```
 for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
     int xx =Math.abs(i-Character.getNumericValue(SS.charAt(0)));
     cal(i, 1, i, xx , SS);
 }
```

For Example `237946732463272737 60` this output my code fails to calculate in specific time
How can i improve my algorithm

Comment: What does *convert a number in the divisible of 3* mean?

Comment: So you want to count all numbers divisible by three which are reachable by the said conversion, within the specified cost?

Comment: First thing you should make use of is the fact that a number divisible by 3 has the property that its digits sum to a number divisible by 3. This is closely related to your cost function.

Comment: you should also give the link of the contest this problem, for a clear problem statement

Comment: [Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/codeagon/challenges/number-power)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem: you need a **dp[P][C][S]** array where **dp[i][j][k]** specifies that you are position **i** in the numerical representation of the number, you have have **j** amount of money and the sum up till now is **k**.
Basic idea is if you change ( or not ) a digit the problem reduces to a sub-problem of (left digits,left money,overall sum) each digit has at most 10 options so to fill each state you will need a loop of 10. So time complexity **O(P * C * S * 10)**. As N is only at max 10^18 at max P=19 ( digits ), C=200 ( as you mentioned) and S at max is 9*18 ( sum of digits ). So this algorithm is decent for given time constraints as well as memory which is **O(P * C * S)**.  
So in addition to your  logic of recursion ,  you  need to use memoization ( storing answer for states already visited) along with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

With problems like this, using recursion to generate all possibilities causes the time taken to grow exponentially as the size of the input grows. If you want an algorithm that does this quickly for large input sizes you would be better of thinking of a way to calculate it without generating all possibilities.

You will probably want the fact that the sum of digits of a number which is divisible by 3 is also divisible by 3.

So perhaps see what the sum of the digits of your original number gives modulo 3. If it is 1 for example, the total change in digit values that you make will need to be 2 modulo 3. Then you can progress from there